# Have something be done

Tags: passive-voice, causative-have

I faced the following sentence in the book "Computer Networks":

> The moral of the story is that all messages must contain considerable redundancy so that active intruders cannot send random junk and **have it be interpreted** as a valid message.

The question is how to understand the **have it be interpreted** part.
Is **have** here the causative and this is the "have something done" with passive voice (we have extra **be** here)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the *be* is optional here: the meaning is slightly different, but only very slightly - a difference of focus.

Without *be*, even though it is not grammatially active, it nevertheless implies an actor: the meaning is something like "command that something or somebody interpret it".

With *be* it is more explicitly passive, with the focus on the "it" and not on the actor: a paraphrase is something like "command that it be interpreted".

Comment: Thank you, Colin. So if I got it right, the focus here is on the random junk rather than on intruder.

Comment: @KirillFertikov: yes. But as I said, the difference is very slight.